# How do I determine if my contribution to an area of research merits publication?

Tags: research-process, publications

I am a new worker in real functions with little experience and few published papers but not in top journals.

I together with my two colleagues found a new characterization of a well-known class of functions (first Baire class). I am pretty sure this is new. However, we cannot decide the extent of its significance because we are unable to find a good application. But suffice it to say there are some old results in the area that admit a very straightforward proof using our characterization. For instance, functions with countable discontinuities can be shown to be of first Baire class using our characterization with a very easy proof.

My question, is this enough for publication? I am afraid to submit it and got a snobbish review. By the way, I am from a third-world country.

Comment: I don't know.  I would say that it is publishable.  And if you are able to show previously known results more simply with your characterization, that is great, and I think worthwhile!

Answer (score 13):

If you don't submit a paper, you're never going to find out it's publishable—unless someone beats you to it. Basically, if you and your colleagues believe you have a publishable advance, then write it up and submit it.

On a related note: have you solicited feedback from colleagues in the field? Has it been presented at a conference somewhere? What have you heard and done to "talk the work up" with colleagues? Has anyone told you it is (or is not) publishable?

Comment: The first sentence says it all....if you want to know if you can, then try and see what happens. A bad review might sting but it won't hurt for long. In the end, you'll be better off by learning how to improve.

Comment: Yes I presented it in a conference and one expert in the field said that our characterization is something new but did not hinted about the significance of our result.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like your work merits **submission**. Whether it merits **publication** depends on the journal. It's always good to consult with experts ahead of time, but failing that the best approach is to find a journal that seems in tune with the results (maybe it's the one where the prior work was published, or one that contains most of the relevant material that you needed for your result). Then submit it and see what happens. In the worst case your paper will be rejected, but then you'll expect to get review feedback, which is really what you're looking for.